# facebook wall with like button and replay box on website

Tags: web, facebook-wall

I am making a website for a band and i want to know if there is a possible option to add a wall to the website with a like button and reaction box like it is on facebook 
i can not find this how to get this done ( i don't want to use a iframe  more like a plugin that only show there post with likebutton and reaction option and so on
with other words copy paste the wall of the band page directly with all options to the website
with friendly greats 
jorgen

Answer (score 0):

What kind of website? Are you using some cms or building something by yourself? How should this "like" functionality behave?

To answer your question as general as it's asked: **Yes it's possible.**

If you're using a content management system you may want to search for a [module that has such functionality](http://drupal.org/project/fblikebutton).

Comment: it is build by hand    its not oly like it is just like if you go on facebook you have a wall if sombody put a picture on there you can like it and react on it  same for a normal post  just like a full facebook wall plugin  with other words just a coppy of the wall you need on your website